# How to connect Azure DevOps in Visual Studio code

Tags: development, spfx-tooling

I have been able to do this with a bit of trial and error but I could do with a bit of clarification before I explain this to anyone in my team as I am still a bit confused !

1. I have a local repo dir
2. Both VSCode and Cmder are both opened in this dir
3. I am connecting to DevOps via a proxy http://myproxy:80
4. I notice a  Personal Access Token with code read/write and read package has been auto created on DevOps and held in the Windows Cred manager
5. VSCode 1.27.2 +  Visual Studio Team Services extension 1.136.0

**VSCode => Application Proxy / User settings**

Proxy = http://myproxy:80
Proxy strict SLL = false

**VSCode Terminal**

```
git config ---global http.proxy
```

http://myaccount:mypassword@myproxy:80  <- this seems to be referenced when I sync changes in VS Code

**Cmder**

```
git config ---global http.proxy
```

http://myproxy:80  <- notice the subtle difference!

```
git config ---list
```

http.proxy shown as above

The key to getting the sync to work is setting the correct remote.origin.url

```
remote.origin.url=https://dev.azure.com/<devOpsAcc>/_git/MyProject
```

When I am asked to run the Command Task. Teams:Times:Signin, I present my own PAT but still asked for a password.